# ASP Net Core: add many to many relationship with IdentityUser

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

i need to add a many to many relationship with UserIdentity in asp net core (i.e:  a user can have many books and a book can have many user owners)

I have the book class:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I have extended the UserIdentity class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<UserBook> UserBooks { get; set; }
}
```

I have created the join table but i don't know how reference the identityuser id

```
public class UserBook
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

How can create correctly a many to many relationship between the identityuser table and another table?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your `UserBook` model class you have used `UserId` of type `int` for `ApplicationUser` but in your `ApplicationUser` model class you are inheriting `IdentityUser` where primary key `Id` is of type `string` by default, that means your `ApplicationUser`'s `Id` is of type `string`. So there will be a primary key type mismatch for `Foreignkey` in `UserBook` table.

**Solution-1:** If you have no problem to keep `ApplicationUser`'s primary key `Id` of type `string`, then just change the `UserId` type to string in `UserBook` model class as follows:

```
public class UserBook
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

**Solution-2:** If you want to change `ApplicationUser`'s primary key `Id` from default  `string` type to `int`, then specify the key type as `int` while you are inheriting `IdentityUser` as follows:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
   public ICollection<UserBook> UserBooks { get; set; }
}
```

Now you have to make changes in `ConfigureServices` method of the Startup class as follows:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser<int>>() // here replace `IdentityUser` with `IdentityUser<int>`
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Now finally your model configuration **(for both Solution-1 and Solution-2)** using  `Fluent Api` should be as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserBook>()
        .HasKey(ub => new { ub.UserId, ub.BookId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserBook>()
        .HasOne(ub => ub.ApplicationUser)
        .WithMany(au => au.UserBooks)
        .HasForeignKey(ub => ub.UserId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<UserBook>()
        .HasOne(ub => ub.Book)
        .WithMany() // If you add `public ICollection<UserBook> UserBooks { get; set; }` navigation property to Book model class then replace `.WithMany()` with `.WithMany(b => b.UserBooks)`
        .HasForeignKey(ub => ub.BookId);
}
```

Comment: I have changed UserId from int to string in UserBook model class. Anyway, when i make a migration i get the following error: The entity type 'UserBook' requires a primary key to be defined.

Comment: @Tom May be you missed my Fluent Api configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, `public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }`

ApplicationUser has a default key type of `string`.

If you do want to use int, simple do:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
```

Be sure to declare this relationship in your DbContext.

*Here's a sample:*

```
entityTypeBuilder.HasKey(pcp => new { pcp.CurrencyPairId, pcp.IsMain })
                .HasName("PartialCurrencyPair_CK_CurrencyPairId_IsMain");

            entityTypeBuilder.HasOne(pcp => pcp.Currency).WithMany(c => c.PartialCurrencyPairs)
                .HasForeignKey(pcp => pcp.CurrencyId)
                .HasConstraintName("PartialCurrencyPairs_Currency_Constraint");
            entityTypeBuilder.HasOne(pcp => pcp.CurrencyPair).WithMany(cp => cp.PartialCurrencyPairs)
                .HasForeignKey(pcp => pcp.CurrencyPairId)
                .HasConstraintName("PartialCurrencyPairs_CurrencyPair_Constraint");
```

**EDIT**

You don't have to explicitly define the generics together with the base class (IdentityUser). You simply do this:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, Role>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<NozomiAuthContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

This assumes Role and ApplicationUser share the same key type of `string`, where they are overloads of IdentityRole and IdentityUser respectively.