# EF Core IdentityUser in many-to-many relation with business model, how to use .Include().ThenInclude()?

Tags: c#, many-to-many, asp.net-identity, ef-core-2.2

Actually I know how to create and use many-to-many relation in regular EF Core DB context, but in my present project I decided to migrate my Identity DB context tables to my ApplicationDbContext, where I keep rest of my business tables:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser>
    {
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<CompanyModel> Companies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CompanyUser> CompaniesUsers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            //many-to-many
            modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyUser>()
                .HasKey(c => new { c.CompanyId, c.UserId });

            /* do I realy need this at all? -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/54612387/12603542 
            modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyUser>()
                .HasOne(cu => cu.AppUser)
                .WithMany(au => au.CompaniesUsers)
                .HasForeignKey(cu => cu.UserId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyUser>()
                .HasOne(cu => cu.CompanyModel)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(cu => cu.CompanyId);
                */
        }
    }
```

I have a relations, where many users may have many companies, so I created Company <-> AppUser many-to-many bridge:

```
public class CompanyUser
    {
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
        public CompanyModel CompanyModel { get; set; }
    }
```

And my AppUser contains navigation property:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
    {
        //(...)
        public ICollection<CompanyUser> CompaniesUsers { get; set; } //many-to-many
    }
```

Same about my CompanyModel:

```
public class CompanyModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        //(...)
        public ICollection<CompanyUser> CompaniesUsers { get; set; } //many-to-many
    }
```

Everything seems to be fine, until I am not trying to retrieve an user with related companies drom DB, where my controller calls DAL method:

```
AppUser userWithLists = _repositoryUser.GetUser(user.Id);
```

And in my repository I try to do that:

```
public AppUser GetUser(string id)
        {
            return _context.Users
                .Include(u => u.CompaniesUsers)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.CompanyModel)
                .Where(u => u.Id == id)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

But **unfortunately** when executing LINQ query on my DB context I am receiving an exception:

> SqlException: Invalid column name 'AppUserId'. Invalid column name
>   'AppUserId'.

With commented out OnModelCreating code I am getting another exception:

> SqlException: Invalid column name 'CompanyModelCompanyId'.

Bridge table T-SQL creation code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CompaniesUsers] (
    [CompanyId] INT            NOT NULL,
    [UserId]    NVARCHAR (450) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_CompaniesUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CompanyId] ASC, [UserId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_CompaniesUsers_Companies_CompanyId] FOREIGN KEY ([CompanyId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Companies] ([CompanyId]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_CompaniesUsers_AppUser_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CompaniesUsers_CompanyId]
    ON [dbo].[CompaniesUsers]([CompanyId] ASC);
```

Comment: What exactly  _context.Users is? Maybe you need _context.AppUser

Comment: @crankedrelic its part of the framework, in `namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` a `public DbSet<TUser> Users { get; set; }`

Comment: Does this also happen with your commented out configuration code? It looks like it's trying to guess the foreign key name as "AppUserId", because you haven't configured it to "UserId".

Comment: @crankedrelic with this I am getting new exception: `SqlException: Invalid column name 'CompanyModelCompanyId'.`

Comment: You get that exception at the same place?

Comment: @crankedrelic yes

Comment: check your CompanyModel configuration. Also as a tip, use better naming conventions as it gets confusing. use CompanyModelsUsers for example instead of CompaniesUsers, AppUserId instead of UserId etc.

Comment: I agree with `CompanyModel`, but I really have no idea where `AppUserId` came from. I belive that it is some **Identity framework** convention, same with `CompanyModelCompanyId`, for searching entity ID. They are not part of any of my models or tables.